# Checkbox Align Table alternatives

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have 5 checkboxes and a table with 6 rows (1 head, 5 body), the table represent choices of the question. How can I align each check box with the first line of each row?

```css
table,
thead,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

table {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-check {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p style="margin-left: 20px;">
<form id='f1'>
  <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='A'></div>
  <br>
  <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='B'></div>
  <br>
  <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='C'></div>
  <br>
  <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='D'></div>
  <br>
  <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='E'></div>
</form>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Event 1</td>
      <td>Event 2</td>
      <td>Event 3</td>
      <td>Event 4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a)</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b)</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c)</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d)</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e)</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</p>
```

I'm not good with CSS, I tried to mess with the developer tools but this is the result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqKuK.png). It seems like the table is already alongside the form which is good, but It only start after the form is finished, maybe it's because of the br I put but without them each check box will be on the top of the others. I thought about putting the check boxes inside the cells but the style would be ruined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was flex missing.Here you go...**

```css
.wrap_my_face {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
table,
thead,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
table {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
form {
  margin-top: 2.2875rem;
}
.form-check {
  margin: -.4125rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <div class="wrap_my_face">
    <form id='f1'>
      <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='A'></div><br>
      <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='B'></div><br>
      <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='C'></div><br>
      <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='D'></div><br>
      <div class='form-check'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='E'></div>
    </form>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
          <td>Event 1</td>
          <td>Event 2</td>
          <td>Event 3</td>
          <td>Event 4</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>a)</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>b)</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>c)</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>d)</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>e)</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This isn't very flexible solution. Having the checkboxes totally independent from the row they are associated with is not good practice - there is no relationship between the checkbox and row, so they can easily get out of alignment through changes in styling, font size, extra text etc.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not consistent, if you have a row with higher height it won't work anymore as intended.

You should add the checkboxes inside every row and use CSS to get rid of all the borders if you want to have a similar result but adaptable to every situation.

Example:

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.wrap_my_face {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

table,
thead,
td {
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.no-border-cell {
  border: 0px;
}

td {
border: 1px solid black;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

table {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

form {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  ;
}

.form-check {
  margin: -.325rem 0;
}
```

```html
    <form id='f1'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td class="no-border-cell"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Event 1</td>
          <td>Event 2</td>
          <td>Event 3</td>
          <td>Event 4</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="border: 0"><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='A'></td>
          <td>a)</td>
          <td>29
            dwqdwqdqw dqw qwd d dqdqd<br>dwqdwqd qw
          </td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border: 0"><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='B'></td>
          <td>b)</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border: 0"><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='C'></td>
          <td>c)</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border: 0"><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='D'></td>
          <td>d)</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="border: 0"><input type='checkbox' class='form-check-input' name='E'></td>
          <td>e)</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>31</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the checkbox is a block element It takes up 100% width of the screen. Even with a negative margin, it will not move. You can add flexbox easier solution in CSS or change the display to an inline element and use floats.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you be so kind and provide here some snippet or code to your solution?